# Barcode generation server side or client side?

Tags: java, angularjs, itext, barcode

Having a requirement to generate bar code, So haven't seen any blog regarding whether creating the the bar code on server side or client side, which is better.

Java and angular js are the technologies using.
All the data required to generate bar code is present on client(UI) side.

Suggest whether it is good to create bar code as a web service or in client side using angular plugin.

If its writing in server side, how can it be transferred to client side, Is it a string ?

Comment: IMHO - Server, the client is the "view" of the bar code and the server is the generator

Comment: That's a matter of opinion IMHO, some dev might implement an API to return a ready to use code bar image, some other one might implement the same API to return the barcode data, some other one might implement both  API

Answer (score 2):

Always go to the server side when doing a task that involves data and security measures.

Answer (score 1):

Its all upto the developer .
But its always good to so such operations at **server side** and keep client side as light as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Really and truly, as long as generating the barcode does not require any interaction from your server in can be done client side (ie. User enters a number, generate barcode, display to user).

However depending on the complexity of your application, it might be advisable to generate the barcode server side (and cache the image) to give the user a more efficient (less load time) experience.